# Attribute changes are not notified and table is not updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to update a table but the update SQL is not performed so the changes has no effect.

Details:

Originally issue.name us 'issue'. I want to change to 'qqqqqqqqqqqq'.

Controller:

```
def update
if params['cancel']
  redirect_to(@issue)
  return
end
@issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
logger.debug "original object"
logger.debug "#{@issue.to_yaml}"
logger.debug 'bulk attribute settings...'
@issue.attributes= params[:issue]
logger.debug "after bulk settings"
logger.debug "#{@issue.to_yaml}"

@issue.events.build(:note=>params[:issue][:description],:verb=>'Edited', :changes=>@issue.textalize_changes)

if @issue.save
  logger.debug "after save"
  logger.debug "#{@issue.to_yaml}"
  redirect_to(@issue)
else
  render :action => "edit"
end
end
```

One additional code fregment might be interesting is the `textalize_changes`:

```
def textalize_changes
r = ""
if changed?
  changes.keys.each do |k|
    r << "#{k.humanize} changed "
    r << "from `#{translate(k,changes[k][0])}` " 
    r << "to `#{translate(k,changes[k][1])}`"
    r << "<br/>"
  end
end
r unless r.blank?
end
```

The result:

- until the line `@issue.save` everything looks correct. I have checked that `@issue` contains all the changes i have made.
- on the user interface no changes I have notified.
- in the log no update SQL is visible. all relevant select and insert is presented but no update - so no change in table `issues`
- even `textalize_changes` has not realize and changes in the object when checking for that (`changed?`)
- If I manually change the attribute in at source code level by `name=XXX` it is working.

I don't know what to check or review at all. The code is so simple that i have no idea at all.

Here is the log of the operation:

```
    original object
    --- !ruby/object:Issue 
    attributes: 
      name: OTTO TEST 2
      assigned_to: "29"
      updated_at: 2010-12-16 10:25:28
      project_id: "1"
      current_estimate: 
      lft: "1"
      original_estimate: 
      priority: 
      id: "10"
      version_id: 
      area_id: 
      description: 
      worktype_id: "2"
      status_id: "5"
      rgt: "2"
      parent_id: 
      created_at: 2010-05-21 07:37:15
      fixed_in_version_id: 
    attributes_cache: {}

    bulk attribute settings...
    WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: description
      [4;36;1mIssue Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT "lft", "rgt", "parent_id" FROM "issues"     WHERE ("issues"."id" = 10) [0m
    after bulk settings
    --- !ruby/object:Issue 
    area: 
    assigned_user: 
    attributes: 
      name: qqqqqqqqqq
      assigned_to: "29"
      updated_at: 2010-12-16 10:25:28
      project_id: "1"
      current_estimate: 
      lft: "1"
      original_estimate: 
      priority: 
      id: "10"
      version_id: 
      area_id: 
      description: 
      worktype_id: "2"
      status_id: "5"
      rgt: "2"
      parent_id: 
      created_at: 2010-05-21 07:37:15
      fixed_in_version_id: 
    attributes_cache: {}

    changed_attributes: {}

    children: 
    events: 
    fixed_in_version: 
iterations: 
marked_for_destruction: false
parent: 
project: 
status: 
timelogs: 
version: 
work_items: 
worktype: 
  [4;35;1mEvent Create (0.0ms)[0m   [0mINSERT INTO "events" ("updated_at", "verb", "external", "issue_id", "note", "changes", "user_id", "created_at") VALUES('2010-12-16 10:33:08', 'Edited', 'f', 10, '', NULL, 1, '2010-12-16 10:33:08')[0m
after save
  [4;36;1mEvent Load (16.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT * FROM "events" WHERE ("events".issue_id = 10) ORDER BY id ASC, created_at ASC[0m
--- &id001 !ruby/object:Issue 
area: 
assigned_user: 
attributes: 
  name: qqqqqqqqqq
  assigned_to: "29"
  updated_at: 2010-12-16 10:25:28
  project_id: "1"
  current_estimate: 
  lft: "1"
  original_estimate: 
  priority: 
  id: "10"
  version_id: 
  area_id: 
  description: 
  worktype_id: "2"
  status_id: "5"
  rgt: "2"
  parent_id: 
  created_at: 2010-05-21 07:37:15
  fixed_in_version_id: 
attributes_cache: {}
```

Technical info:

- Op system: winXP
- rails: rails 2.3.4

Additional info:

I have a bulk operation with the same purpose which is working correctly. I really don't know the differences:

```
def update_multiple  
if params['cancel']
  redirect_to issues_path
  return
end
@issues = Issue.find(params[:issue_ids])
@issues.each do |issue|
  issue.attributes= params[:issue].reject {|k,v| v.blank? }
  issue.apply_template_on_name_change
  issue.events.build(:note=>params[:issue][:description],:verb=>"Edited", :changes=>issue.textalize_changes)
  issue.save!
end
flash[:notice]="Issues updated!"
redirect_to issues_path
 end
```

Additional info:

If I replace `@issue.attributes= params[:issue]` by `@issue.attributes= params[:issue].reject {|k,v| v.blank? }` it apply changes and working. But it is not the one I really want. I want to change everything at once. I am going crazy.

Comment: Have you checked your validations, or before_save filters?

Comment: Code segmen `if @issue.save  redirect_to(@issue)` would take care of such a thing. I have already checked and runs into this the success case. (I have used logger to and debugger to trace down these steps, but still no update operation)

Comment: I would like to stress that just before `save` the object `@issue` has the changes. (i could print out changed attribute). ant the method `changed?` response false too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue in awesome nested set.

This plugin reloads the object just before executing nested set operations.:  I have changed the controller in the following way:

```
@issue.parent_issue= params[:issue][:parent_issue]
@issue.attributes= params[:issue].reject {|k,v| 'parent_issue'==k }
```

this the best solutions now.

note: parent_issue is for setting the parent of the given entity and using the same form as for the rest of the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try save with exclamation, like `@issue.save!` to see the errors.