# Attributes passed to .build() dont show up in the query

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

Hope your all enjoying your hollydays.

Ive run into a pretty funny problem when trying to insert rows into a really really simple database table.
The basic idea is pretty simple. The user selects one/multiple users in a multiselect which are supposed to be added to a group.

This piece of code will insert a row into the user_group_relationships table, but the users id always

```
   @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])

   params[:newMember][:users].each do |uid|
      # For debugging purposes.
      puts 'Uid:'+uid

      @rel = @group.user_group_relationships.build( :user_id => uid.to_i )          
      @rel.save 

    end
```

The user id always gets inserted as null even though it is clearly there. You can see the uid in this example is 5, so it should work.

> Uid:5
>   ...
>   SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO
>   "user_group_relationships"
>   ("created_at", "group_id",
>   "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES
>   ('2010-12-27 14:03:24.331303', 2,
>   '2010-12-27 14:03:24.331303', NULL)

Any ideas why this fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `user_id` is not `attr_accessible` in the `UserGroupRelationship` model.

You might also want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449337/attribute-changes-are-not-notified-and-table-is-not-updated) it may be relevant.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thank you! I guess thats just the pain if learning a new language/framework, you don't really know about all the tools that are available to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think @zabba's answer is probably the one you need to look for but i would suggest a couple of extra things here.

Your "Group" and "User" models are connected to each other thru the "UserGroup" model it seems. You would have relationship

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_group_relationships
  has_many :users, :through => :user_group_relationships
end

class UserGroupRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In your controller

```
# Find the group
@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])

# For each user id, find the user and add the user_group_relationship
params[:newMember][:users].each{|u| @group.users << User.find(u) }
```

Read up Rails Documentation on associations and the methods generated automatically for you when associations are defined. More often than not, working with association is easier than you might think! I discover new APIs in Rails constantly! :) Good Luck!

Comment: Great solution! I still ended up using Zabba's answer since it, in this case, seems to be the more efficient way to go. Your suggestion came in handy in another controller though. :D